# Why does it take 60 minutes before you can collect money from an auction's sale?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Why does it take 60 minutes before you can collect money from an auction's sale?

On the contrary, when you put an item to sale, it becomes available for buyer instantly.

Comment: To prevent scams?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The auction message delays were introduced in [patch 2.2.0](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Patch_2.2.0).  There doesn't seem to be a definitive answer about why Blizzard introduced it, but [this thread](http://www.wowhead.com/forums&topic=112099/what-exactly-is-the-reason-for-auction-house-and-mail-delays) discusses reasons as to why.  Some include:

- Getting gold sellers off the market (this seems to be the biggest reason)
- Getting you to play longer
- Allowing GM's a chance to review transactions and aid in fraudulent transactions

A lot of the people on that thread also remember seeing on the official patch notes a reason as to why the delay was introduced, and it was to get gold sellers of the market.  Unfortunately, it looks like the official patch notes are no longer available off the games website.

Comment: Th delays were introduced with path 2.1.3. You can still access the mentioned patch notes using archive.org: http://web.archive.org/web/20071102035249/http://www.worldofwarcraft.com/patchnotes/patch2p10.html

Comment: That seems to be talking about mail in general that contains money.  The 2.2.0 patch seems to be for auction-mail only.  Still, it provides insight, and good thinking about using an archival site!